# Unable to execute vw-varinfo command

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I installed Vowpal Wabbit 7.3.0 on linux mint. I was able to use the vw command training model and getting predictions.

However, I am not able execute vw-varinfo command. I am not able to find this command in vw --help. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

`vw-varinfo` is located in the [utl](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/tree/master/utl) directory. You can add it to your `$PATH`.